# How to set React state with a function

Tags: reactjs

I need to get the current `url` from the browser address bar and set that value to a `react` state's `currentPath`.

So this is my code looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./css/custom.css";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";

import NavigationBar from "./pages/homepage-components/1-navbar";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import Post from "./pages/Post";

function NavigationHeader() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return location.pathname;
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentPath: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      currentPath: NavigationHeader, //even tried NavigationHeader() and NavigationHeader.toString
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {/* --------------- Navigation Bar --------------- */}
        <NavigationBar />
        Path is: {this.state.currentPath}

        {/* --------------- End of Navigation Bar --------------- */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/post" component={Post} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**But it doen't update the `currentPath`** because where it says `Path is: {this.state.currentPath}` it is not showing. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Hooks won't work in `class component`, they are meant for `function components` only.

Comment: @PrathapReddy how can I then change my class component to a function component to get this done?

Comment: Check out the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) on how to use `useLocation` and update `pathname` on location change. It's declarative.

Answer (score 1):

Although setting `currentPath` is meaningless and your example is a bad practice you can just render your `NavigationHeader` with `setLocation` prop:

```
function NavigationHeader({ setLocation }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLocation(location.pathname)
  }, [location.pathname])

  return null;
}
```

...

```
{/* --------------- Navigation Bar --------------- */}
<NavigationHeader setLocation={ (currentPath) => this.setState({ currentPath }) }/>
```

---

To make it more clean you can refactor your `NavigationHeader` so that it contain `Path is: {location.pathname}`:

```
function NavigationHeader() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return <p>Path is: {location.pathname}</p>;
}


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      {/* --------------- Navigation Bar --------------- */}
      <NavigationBar />
      <NavigationHeader />

      {/* --------------- End of Navigation Bar --------------- */}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/post" component={Post} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't we need to add `location` as hook dependency instead of `[]`!? To listen to path change updates?

Comment: If you want to do any conditional rendering for `NavigationBar` depends on the value I get from `NavigationHeader`, is it possible within the `<Router> // conditional rendering </Router>` ?

Comment: yes, it is possible, but still a bad practice. try isolating into smallest reusable components. in your case if `NavigationBar` and `NavigationHeader ` share same state it would be reasonable to combine them inside of another component, f.e. `Navigation`. but this is a completely different topic

Answer (score 0):

You can get current url from window.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
  currentPath: window.location.href
 });
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't update the `currentPath` for every route change.